# Falha no formulário php

Tags: php, formulário

Boa tarde, pessoal.
Estou com um problema no formulário do site. Não consigo enviar e quando envia, não envia o conteúdo do campo mensagem. Segue o código html e php.
o Link para o site é este [aqui](http://marilza.esy.es/) , tentei colocar aqui o código mas ultrapassou o limite de caracteres.

Segue o código do form.

```
<?php
      //1 – Definimos Para quem vai ser enviado o email
      $para = "juliairacema@gmail.com";
      //2 - resgatar o nome digitado no formulário e  grava na variavel $nome
      $nome = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $empresa = $_POST['company'];
      $telefone = $_POST['personal_phone']; 


      // 3 - resgatar o assunto digitado no formulário e  grava na variavel //$assunto
      $assunto = "Contato pelo site";
       //4 – Agora definimos a  mensagem que vai ser enviado no e-mail
      $mensagem = "<strong>Nome:  </strong>".$nome;
      $mensagem .="<strong>E-mail:  </strong>".$email;
      $mensagem .="<strong>Empresa:  </strong>".$empresa;
      $mensagem .="<strong>Telefone para contato:  </strong>".$telefone;
      $mensagem .= "<br><strong>Mensagem: </strong>".$_POST['custom_fields[155015]'];

    //5 – agora inserimos as codificações corretas e  tudo mais.
      $headers =  "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
      $headers .= "From: ".$para."\n"; //Vai ser //mostrado que  o email partiu deste email e seguido do nome
      $headers .= "X-Sender: smtp-relay.gmail.com\n"; //email do servidor //que enviou
      $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP  v".phpversion()."\n";
      $headers .= "X-IP:  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
      $headers .= "Return-Path:  ".$para."\n"; //caso a msg //seja respondida vai para  este email.
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

    mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);  //função que faz o envio do email.
 ?>
```

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Coloque o html do form que está utilizando.

Comment: Você já deu um var_dump no $_POST para ver o que está sendo recebido?

Comment: É bom saber que: se uma resposta resolveu seu problema, marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 4):

Não é falha no formulário!

A falha é no modo como recupera campo mensagem no PHP

Faça assim:

```
 $msg = $_POST['custom_fields'];

 $mensagem .= "<br><strong>Mensagem: </strong>".$msg[155015];
```

> array no PHP é sempre associativo, mesmo que o índice seja numérico

- Quando você coloca um "name" com [] colchetes ele é enviado na forma de array para o receptor. Colchetes tratam os **elementos do mesmo nome** como um array.
- Quando você envia seu formulário com o campo mensagem com o texto `Falha no formulário php da Julia Iracema Figueira` ele será resgatado na seguinte forma no PHP: `Array ( [155015] => Falha no formulário php da Julia Iracema Figueira )`
- Portanto para recuperar essa mensagem é como descrito acima!

Outrossim, não vejo necessidade de enviar a mensagem na forma de array, visto que há somente um campo com esse `name`. Bastaria no textarea do form `name="custom_fields"` e no PHP `$_POST['custom_fields']`

---

**BONUS**

---

Arrays associativos são estruturas onde cada elemento é identificado por uma chave única.

Os Arrays podem conter chaves e valores dos mais variados tipos numa mesma estrutura, até porque, não existe Arrays tipados. [exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/Z8sn9u)

Comment: gostei do bonus